# How to change locale for a conversation in runtme

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm using botframework composer with multi language and want each user to be able to select preferred language/locale. After resolving the local code for his selection with a choice dialog, how can I set it in conversation so that his locale setting in his device will be overruled for rest of conversation?

Changing locale in emulator works fine, want same behaviour after user selection.

Setting turn.locale works for one turn, but is reset on next turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supposing you don't have control over the client, which would be the best.

You can resort to an old overload on the ever-growing hierarchy of bot adapters that hasn't been marked as deprecated.

You'd have to use the `PostAsync` method (`api/post-messages` endpoint) in the following controller (showing the one created by the current set of bot framework templates just for comparison):

```cs
    [Route("api")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter StreamingAdapter;
        private readonly BotFrameworkAdapter PostAdapter;
        private readonly ConversationLocales ConversationLocales;
        private readonly IBot Bot;

        public BotController(
            IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter streamingAdapter,
            BotFrameworkAdapter postAdapter,
            ConversationLocales conversationLocales,
            IBot bot)
        {
            StreamingAdapter = streamingAdapter;
            PostAdapter = postAdapter;
            Bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost("messages"), HttpGet("messages")]
        public async Task PostOrStreamingAsync()
        {
            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await StreamingAdapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
        }

        [HttpPost("post-messages")]
        public async Task<InvokeResponse> PostAsync([FromBody] Activity activity)
        {
            var savedLocale = ConversationLocales.GetLocaleForConversation(activity.Conversation.Id);

            activity.Locale = savedLocale ?? activity.Locale;

            return await PostAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync(string.Empty, activity, Bot.OnTurnAsync, default);
        }
    }
```

That's supposing you implement a `ConversationLocales` service that allows you to keep the selected locale for each conversation id.

In the code above we're using the `BotFrameworkAdapter` adapter instead of `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter`, however the `AdapterWithErrorHandler` used in the templates inherits indirectly from `BotFrameworkAdapter`, so you could do something like this in `ConfigureServices` to register "both" adapters:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AdapterWithErrorHandler>());
services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkAdapter>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AdapterWithErrorHandler>());
```

To have a single adapter instance.

Using this method the adapter won't be able to use the bot channel streaming endpoints, but that shouldn't be much of a trouble, as long as you don't use the speech client.

You can also read some other details that might be relevan to you in my blog post [How does a Bot Builder v4 bot work?](https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/how-does-a-bot-builder-v4-bot-work/), it's a bit dated but still valid.

**UPDATE** - Found a better solution

This one works with the current wave of adapters and uses the messages pipeline, so it's "modern".

**It also requires you to use a custom runtime, that you'll customize as follows.**

**1 - Create the following middleware**

```cs
public class LocaleSelectionMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<string> _userLocale;

    public LocaleSelectionMiddleware(UserState userState)
    {
        _userLocale = userState.CreateProperty<string>("locale");
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (turnContext is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
        }

        var userLocale = await _userLocale.GetAsync(turnContext, () => turnContext.Activity.Locale);

        turnContext.Activity.Locale = userLocale;
        (turnContext as TurnContext).Locale = userLocale;

        await next(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

**2 - Configure the middleware in the adapter in `GetBotAdapter()` in `Startup.cs`**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.HostingEnvironment = env;
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    //...
    public BotFrameworkHttpAdapter GetBotAdapter(IStorage storage, BotSettings settings, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState, IServiceProvider s)
    {
        var adapter = IsSkill(settings)
            ? new BotFrameworkHttpAdapter(new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(this.Configuration), s.GetService<AuthenticationConfiguration>())
            : new BotFrameworkHttpAdapter(new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(this.Configuration));

        adapter
            .UseStorage(storage)
            .UseBotState(userState, conversationState)
            .Use(new RegisterClassMiddleware<IConfiguration>(Configuration))
            .Use(new LocaleSelectionMiddleware(userState)) // <-- Add the middleware here
            .Use(s.GetService<TelemetryInitializerMiddleware>());

        //...
        return adapter;
    }

    //...
}
```

**3 - Set the user.locale property in any dialog**

Set the `user.locale` property from any dialog, and the next turn will have the desired locale, and will be persisted in the user state, until they change it again.

Comment: unfortunately I'm working in bot framework composer - not sure how to implement this there (newest experimental version where there is no runtime folder any more)

Comment: Hi, hmmm, will take a look at it, BTW, which release are you working with, I'm just trying to get started with version 686a144 and it aborts while creating the initial project... you like living on the edge, right? 

Comment: Although I did get to see a **Custom runtime** location configuration in the **Project settings**

Comment: Thanks Miguel for this great support!

Comment: Glad to help 

Comment: @MiguelVeloso
Hey Miguel, it's not at all clear in the Microsoft Docs how to create an extension / middleware for Bot Framework Composer. Can you help me out? I want to achieve the same thing as OP on this question but I can't figure out how to add middleware to composer. Custom runtime, export runtime, etc. are all new concepts to me...

Comment: Hi @JohnKim, middleware are perhaps the easiest components to implement. I would suggest that you take a look here: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet#middleware. You'll find very simple examples that should help you get started. It's also very important that you're clear on the pipeline concepts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware.

Comment: @MiguelVeloso
Your own github's exploration bot helped me a lot more. MS's samples don't include a *minimal* full project that actually uses the samples. Copying your directory structure and modifying the csproj by referring to yours helped me a lot. Anyway, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Good, I didn't remember I had that project , could you get it running? any doubts about it?

Comment: @MiguelVeloso
I got it running! I created a dynamic multi-prompt with buttons for each locale that the bot supports, and it works! But now I have a different problem... I have a root bot with skills. The locale doesn't sync with the root bot despite calling the skill with "Activity Processed : false", which should be maintaining the root bot's turn context. How can I pass the locale variable of my root bot to my skill every time the root bot hands off to the skill, for all utterances in the skill?

Comment: Hi, glad you got it working. I haven't worked with skills yet, so I can't help much there, but perhaps you could explore the turnContext.TurnSate property. Anyway that should  probably go to another question 

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement, Is this solution present anywhere?

Comment: Hi @MiguelVeloso, could you please share this C# Bot v4 SDK solution - I tried using the snippets you provided but I cant get it working.